# jquery json to be parsed by grails

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, grails

I have an ajax that is successfully passing things into my controller

```
var ids = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
if (ids.length>0) {
    var names = [];
    for (var i=0, il=ids.length; i < il; i++) {
        var name = grid.jqGrid('getCell', ids[i], 'uniqueIdentifyingName');
        names.push(name);
    }
}
```

Then I created an alert that spits this out so I know they are in there:

```
"alex's names: other test,test"
```

Now I would like to pass as data.

I am currently passing them using ajax using

```
data: {'names':JSON.stringify(names)},
dataType: 'json'
```

But I can't parse it in the grails controller

I am currently doing this:

```
List<JSON> Mynames = JSON.parse(params.names)
Mynames.each{println "MY name is: $Mynames"}
```

Which is outputting:

```
MY name is: [other test, test]
MY name is: [other test, test]
```

How can I parse this?

Comment: I am trying to get it to output 
MY name is: other test
MY name is: test

Comment: I am not a grails user. But, shouldn't it be transparent if you pass the `names` AJAX parameter without using `JSON.stringify` on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of printing the whole `Mynames` object in each iteration, print out the current item using `it`

`Mynames.each{ println "MY name is: $it" }`